# Creating a dual y-axis one on top of each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to create in R a graph with Dual y-axis similar to the graph below. Is there such option? In ggplot2? Thank you for your help!

Data: structure(list(Month = structure(c(16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 
16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 
16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 
16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 
17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 
17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501), class = "Date"), 
    Year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
    2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
    2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 
    2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017
    ), Sales = c(268377, 84235, 392020, 270706, 273254, 22255, 
    386118, 23253, 65497, 106306, 123331, 385079, 186158, 146892, 
    237677, 158845, 125116, 16009, 217467, 227434, 95821, 30820, 
    22241, 261339, 217884, 49189, 217724, 450000, 102882, 304524, 
    328485, 166489, 236167, 227174, 55794, 362478, 48639, 83485, 
    3320, 348728, 178646, 390000, 98342, 225186, 114795, 168494, 
    349530, 275178), moving_average_of_sales = c(227337, 226970, 
    232838.6, 249849.3, 251940.8, 221772.2, 240692.5, 216177.9, 
    214923.1, 189202.1, 174697.5, 204781.9, 184195.7, 171814.3, 
    168256.6, 181915.6, 155815.4, 155091, 170288, 182400.8, 179649.8, 
    144223.9, 127832.2, 139276.9, 137297.6, 126332, 135592.8, 
    178991.9, 167533.4, 175242.4, 198508.8, 212075.7, 233468.3, 
    230051.8, 213842.8, 245171.7, 228263.2, 191611.7, 181655.5, 
    186075.9, 171092, 193443.1, 179660.6, 179461.8, 185361.9, 
    165963.5, 196052.6, 215221.9)), row.names = c(NA, 48L), class = "data.frame")

[image]

Comment: looks like multiple plot panes. See `facet_wrap` e.g. https://plot.ly/ggplot2/facet_wrap/

Comment: Your data is not time-series data. You will need to provide more information/context on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong data. I re-posted the one with time series and  that should better reflect the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use ggarrange from ggpubr. If you save the 2 plots as p1 and p2 then

```
ggpubr::ggarrange(p1, p2, nrow = 2, align = "v")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004459/9517359